# large size Images not uploading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on a project where user can  post the add and add the images  to upload,but i am having a problem small size image is working  but when user add a larger image  it take long time to upload and not show anything here is my code

```
 function cropper_now(){
 var $previews = $('.preview');
 var cropBoxData;
 var canvasData;
 $('#image').cropper({
 aspectRatio : 1 / 1,
 viewMode: 1,
 minCropBoxHeight : 200,
 minContainerHeight : 200,
 zoomOnWheel : false,
 zoomable: false,
 built: function () {
 $('#image').cropper('setCanvasData', canvasData);
 $('#image').cropper('setCropBoxData', cropBoxData);
 console.log( $('#image').cropper("getData"));
 },


 crop: function (e) {
 var json = [
'{"x":' + e.x,
'"y":' + e.y,
'"height":' + e.height,
'"width":' + e.width,
'"rotate":' + e.rotate + '}'
  ].join();

$('input[name="imagecropperdata"]').val(json);
}
});
```

Comment: This could be problem related to your database. Contact your host and see if there is a limitation.

Comment: my database has no limitation  @Ronnie Oosting

Comment: Can you check the `upload_max_filesize` ini directive?

Comment: i have checked it and its not there

Comment: Can you try .htaccess? php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M (any value you want).

Comment: By the way, is it the bigger image cannot be uploaded, or does it take ages until it is uploaded and you want to have this faster?

Comment: its the large image  which is not uploading,i have tested upload 2mb image  and it work's fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158512/discussion-between-ronnie-oosting-and-user1797958).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open `php.ini` and search for: `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`.
2. Change it to this: 
   `upload_max_filesize = 10M` 
   `post_max_size = 10M`
3. After modifying `php.ini` file, you need to **restart** your HTTP server.

NOTE: If you can't modify your php.ini file contact your webhost. They might be able to change it (or not).